# Download a files from amazon s3 server with out using aws sdk

Tags: java, android, rest, amazon-s3

My requirement is download a files from Amazon s3 with out using Aws sdk for java and using rest api calls.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question. If your question is "how do I do this?", please explain what you have already tried.

Comment: Ok. So I got response after successfully uploaded the files into amazon s3. In that response having location,date,success code etc..So What I need to pass to get the file with get request.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the file publicly accessible, you can use a simple url to download it. If you need it to be private you will need to use an api or a tool which handles the authorization for you.

You can make the file public as part of the upload api call or after the fact using the AWS Console.

You can also create expiring urls that are only usable for a set period of time using the api.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know you can't set up an expiring url using the AWS Console, so you have to use the api in some fashion. That could be via the command line tools though, if that helps.